# Android Studio Tabbed Activity (Swipe Views) View Pager Check if Tabbed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabbed-activity

I made a new Project in Android Studio with a Tabbed Activity which have the Navigation Style Swipe Views (View Pager). How can I now find out which Fragment is active and if the user has tabbed? Is there any way to check that?

So I made no changes with the Code I just want to check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the selected Tab of a viewPager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24909452/how-to-get-the-selected-tab-of-a-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `setMenuVisibility` method in fragment to check if it is visible or not

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean visible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
    if (visible) {
          //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked correctly. Before I make another question, is there any way to check what Fragment is active too? So Fragment one, or what ever?

Comment: OK solved. In the upper method you can do : this.getArguments().get("section_number") than you get the right fragment id